# Access (VBA) Hiding/Protecting a single Module

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is there a way to hide/protect a single module from the rest of all other modules?

For example, I have a Login Module that protects the front end of the Access but I need just the Login Module to be protected differently from all of my other modules.

I know that I can have the Protection and Lock project for viewing from My New App Properties. But this covers all the vba modules/class objects.

Comment: Not individual modules, no.

Comment: Always distribute `mde/accde` Databases! Users should not be able to change anything. For more security protect code with password (otherwise it can be imported into a `mdb/accdb`). For your company enviroment use the runtime.

Answer (score 1):

well you can certainly hide it from being displayed in the navigation/database window just like you can hide any other object. right-click, object-properties, then attributes-->check the hidden box. note that this won't hide it from the VB Editor, just the database nav window.

as far as password protection goes, no. it's all or nothing.

you can consider moving that module to an external database, and make it an mde/accde, and then set a reference to it. although, this could get you into all kinds of other problems you probably don't want to get into.